# Redefine reference to topmost window (window.top)

Tags: javascript

My goal is to override the reference to the topmost window for all scripts that are executed in an iframe. I have the following code which was tested to work in IE 8+ and FireFox 3,6+ but does not work in Chrome 19.

```
var top = "test";
console.debug(top);
```

This outputs: "test" in IE and FireFox, but shows a reference to the top window in chrome. Is it possible that Chrome uses a mechanism to avoid the reference from being overriden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Issue 10279:   window.top shadowing differs between JSC and V8](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10279)

[Issue 26220:   window.top can't be hidden with var (unlike other browsers)](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26220)