# Why isn't Chrome running this Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The script works perfect in FF and IE, but not in Chrome. Could someone help med to locate the problem?

The if statmenst seems not to be runned when they are supposed to, they do nothing when the should.

```
var top = 285;
var bottom = 650;

var pageheight, maxscroll;


window.onload = function(){

    pageheight = document.body.offsetHeight;

    maxscroll = pageheight - (bottom+40);

}

    window.onscroll = function(){

        var element = document.getElementById("guide-menu");

        if(window.pageYOffset < top){

            element.style.position = "absolute";
            element.style.top = "300px";

        }

        if(window.pageYOffset > top){

            element.style.top = "10px";
            element.style.position = "fixed";
            element.style.marginTop = "0px";

        }

        if(window.pageYOffset > maxscroll){

            element.style.position = "absolute";

            element.style.marginTop = (pageheight - bottom - 40) + "px";

        }

}
```

Comment: What are the values top top and maxscroll ?

Comment: It's not a standard property, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollY) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"top" has different meaning in chrome. Just try to rename top variable.

Answer (score 2):

The "top" variable returns the topmost browser window. Chrome is the only major browser not supporting overriding this variable.

Renaming your variable to something like "myTop" works perfectly.

This code works well.

```
    var myTop = 285;
    var bottom = 650;

    var pageheight, maxscroll;


    window.onload = function(){
        pageheight    = document.body.offsetHeight;
        maxscroll     = pageheight - (bottom+40);

        window.onscroll = function()
        {
            var element = document.getElementById("guide-menu");
            if(window.pageYOffset < myTop)
            {
                element.style.position = "absolute";
                element.style.top = "300px";
            }

            if(window.pageYOffset > myTop)
            {
                element.style.top = "10px";
                element.style.position = "fixed";
                element.style.marginTop = "0px";
            }

            if(window.pageYOffset > maxscroll)
            {
                element.style.position = "absolute";
                element.style.marginTop = (pageheight - bottom - 40) + "px";
            }
        }
    }
```

By the way, check that you are puting the right conditions for the IF statements. If you want a menu which scrolls with the webpage, then you have to exchange the two first if conditions.

Comment: A bad thing by Chrome there imo... You can't override the value top at all... setting `var top = 123;` does nothing!!? Yet another bug to add to Chrome's list.

Comment: That has been discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063644/redefine-reference-to-topmost-window-window-top

Comment: Ah - thanks for the link - it only affects `var top;` when it is set in the global scope... so not so bad then... it's good practice to wrap your code in an anon function anyway so this usually wouldn't be a problem.